# C++20 return a tuple in ternary statement

Tags: c++, c++20, conditional-operator, ternary, stdtuple

I have a small function that returns three values. I use a `std::tuple` to facilitate returning of multiple values.

What the function returns is determined by one variable, if the variable is not zero it returns one tuple, else it returns another one. Because I use C++20 I just use curly brackets (`{}`) to build the tuples.

I think using a ternary statement would be perfect, but the following doesn't work:

```
#include <tuple>

using std::tuple;

double hue(double b, double g, double r, double d, double i);

tuple<double, double, double> HSL_pixel(double b, double g, double r, double i, double x, double z) {
    double s = x + z;
    double d = z - x;
    double avg = s / 2;
    return d ? {hue(b, g, r, d, i), d / (1 - abs(s - 1)), avg} : {0.0, 0.0, avg};
}
```

In Visual Studio 2022, an error is detected at the first opening curly bracket position, it says: "expected an expression".

Changing to if else statement fixed the problem:

```
tuple<double, double, double> HSL_pixel(double b, double g, double r, double i, double x, double z) {
    double s = x + z;
    double d = z - x;
    double avg = s / 2;
    if (d) {
        return { hue(b, g, r, d, i), d / (1 - abs(s - 1)), avg };
    } 
    else {
        return { 0.0, 0.0, avg };
    }
}
```

But I want to use ternary. How can I use ternary in this case?

Comment: What is `hue`? What does it return?

Comment: Side note a tuple of 3 floating point numbers is not a strong color type. Just declare your own color struct : `struct color_t { float red; float green; float blue; }` and use that. That way you can't accidentally pass tuples that are not colors to functions that should only work on colors and you get readable red/green/blue values too. `std::tuple` is intended to be used in template library code not as an "easy" way out to safe on a bit of typing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grammatically, you cannot use a *braced-init-list* with the conditional operator. So just this is ill-formed:

```cpp
int a = true ? 1 : {};
```

You have to write this instead:

```cpp
int b = true ? 1 : int{};
```

Which in your example that's:

```cpp
cond ? tuple{a, b, c} : tuple{d, e, f}
```

instead of:

```cpp
cond ? {a, b, c} : {d, e, f}
```

Or, if you really prefer to use *braced-init-list*, then you'll have to use `if`/`else` (or just `if`). Just a style choice at that point.

Answer (score 0):

As @Barry has already pointed out, a *braced-init-list* cannot appear as one of two expressions in a conditional operator.

Besides that issue, returning tuples is also not a good idea because it's unclear from the signature of a function what `tuple<double, double, double>` actually means. You could improve code quality a lot by using simple `struct`s instead:

```cpp
struct rgb_color {
    double r, g, b; // note: float precision is almost always sufficient for colors,
                    //       your monitor can only handle 8 or 10 bits anyway
    // define all comparisons
    friend auto operator<=>(const rgb_color&, const rgb_color&) = default;
};

struct hsl_color {
    double h, s, l; // consider using hue, saturation, lightness instead

   friend auto operator<=>(const hsl_color&, const hsl_color&) = default;
};
```

With simple `struct`s like these, you get almost all the functionality of `std::tuple` that's worth caring about, and code becomes much clearer:

```cpp
double hue(rgb_color color, double d, double i);

hsl_color HSL_pixel(rgb_color color, double i, double x, double z) {
    double s = x + z;
    double d = z - x;
    double avg = s / 2;
    return d ? hsl_color{hue(color, d, i), d / (1 - abs(s - 1)), avg}
             : hsl_color{0.0, 0.0, avg};
}
```

I'm still not sure what `d`, `i`, `x` and `z` mean, but they're probably worth bundling up too in some way.